# fadeIn and faceOut effect in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to add fade function in the following script. I need that the `css element` which gets style `display: none` fadeOut and the `css element` which gets style `display: block` fadeIn. How shall I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contacts").toggle(function() {
        $("#phone_2").css("display", "block");
        $("#phone_1").css("display", "none");
    }, function() {
        $("#phone_1").css("display", "block");
        $("#phone_2").css("display", "none");
    });
});​
```

Comment: I edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113551/601179) to a lot cleaner way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contacts").toggle(function() {
        $("#phone_2").fadeIn();
        $("#phone_1").fadeOut();
    }, function() {
        $("#phone_1").fadeIn();
        $("#phone_2").fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

By the way, you can do that **a lot simpler** with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contacts").click(function() {
        $("#phone_2, #phone_1").toggle(400);
    });
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zZjpd/1)

Comment: @VirendraRajput. I guess people love to write... 6 lines instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contacts").toggle(function() {
        $("#phone_2").fadeIn();
        $("#phone_1").fadeOut();
    }, function() {
        $("#phone_1").fadeIn();
        $("#phone_2").fadeOut();
    });
});​

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKnR/)

And the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contacts").toggle(function() {
        $("#phone_2").fadeIn();
        $("#phone_1").fadeOut();
    }, function() {
        $("#phone_1").fadeIn();
        $("#phone_2").fadeOut();
    });
});​
```